# Null value on load for option tag using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to bind all the values to option tag using Angular JS. But, my issue is that, on load the null value is getting appended. And when I set a value in JS code, it sets only the first value, but it won't get changed as selected attribute when I check in browser console. And how can I have my own value to the option tag.

### JS

This sets only first value at all time as "selected" attribute

```
    statePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for(index in data) {
            console.log("ID:"+data[index].id+" Name:"+data[index].name);
            if (data[index].id) {
                $scope.states.push({
                    id:data[index].id,
                    name:data[index].name                   
                });                 
            }
        }
        $scope.statelist = $scope.states;
        $scope.state = $scope.statelist[0];
```

But, when I change the option value and check in browser, it still shows first. Its because of the above statement. And how can I set option values which I get from DB as

```
<option value="1">AP</option>
<option value="2">TN</option>
<option value="3">KN</option>
```

Actually its saving as

```
<option value="0">AP</option>
<option value="1">TN</option>
<option value="2">KN</option>
```

### HTML Code

```
<select  ng-model="state" ng-change="changeState()" ng-options="state.name for state in statelist"></select>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your ng-options code

Comment: @BKM, I've updated my code. I've added html code.

Comment: When you use ng-options it will show the option value as 0,1,2.... But actually it will save the value of what you give in ng-options

Comment: So, where should I change?

Comment: Please provide your statelist json array

Comment: Ok. [{"id":1,"name":"AP"},{"id":2,"name":"TN"},{"id":3,"name":"KN"}]

Comment: I've just sent the JSON array. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ng-options as

```
ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in statelist"
```

In your controller do this:

```
$scope.state = $scope.statelist[0].id;
```

Comment: No change :( Rather the first value is null

Comment: But, it will show id's instead of names, right? and No change as well